# Windows 2003 - How to reconnect a 2 month offline domain controller

Tags: windows-server-2003, domain-controller, reconnect

Will I have a problem if I reconnect a 2 month offline domain controller on the network?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The offline limit for a domain controller Windows 2003 is 180 days.

You should be fine.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/198793/

Comment: Thanks! but It isn't going to introduce conflicts on AD catalog?

Comment: According to that KB article, Windows will retain knowledge of that domain controller in AD for 180 days and therefore there should be no conflict.

"# A domain controller can successfully return to the domain after a longer time offline.
# Knowledge of deleted objects is retained longer on the originating domain controller."

Comment: The 180 day tombstone lifetime was introduced with SP1 and was not "retroactive" for servers\domains installed prior to SP1. If you installed your servers\domain prior to SP1 and did not manually change the tombstobe lifetime to 180 days after installing SP1 then you may have issues reintroducing that domain controller, as the original tombstone lifetime was 60 days.